# How to remove format and informat in proc sql

Tags: sql, format, sas

I googled and found that one can specify `format` in `proc sql` by

```
proc sql;
create table t1 as
select var1 length=20 label='mylabel' format=$20. informat=$20. 
from db;
quit;
```

I know I can remove the `format` and `informat` by data step, but I want to know how to do it in `proc sql`.

Thanks!

Comment: @Joe, I was trying to use `proc compare` to compare two datasets. The only difference now is the `format` for some variables. The `format` in target variable is blank. That's why I want to 'remove' the format for my compared one.

Comment: I don't know how to handle it in SQL but you can use `proc datasets` instead without having to rewrite the dataset: 

`proc datasets lib=libname memtype=data;
   modify dsname; 
     attrib _all_ format=;
run;`

Comment: Ah, okay.  Those variables still technically have a format, but it's not stored that way.  I suspect it's not possible to do that in `PROC SQL`.

Comment: Good point. @DaBigNikoladze Thanks.

Comment: I post my previous comment as an answer just for clarity.

Comment: Since your previous comment was an answer, that's the right thing to do!

Comment: @liuminzhao I would be careful about doing this during a PROC COMPARE, by the way.  Sometimes, format differences matter!  In particular, i've had serious problems with production code because a PROC IMPORT from excel applied a format that was shorter than my data, and while I was setting it correctly (the known data length first, then excel), because the known data length had the default format and excel did not, the excel format caused data truncation when outputting data to text files.

Comment: @Joe Nice comments! I will be careful with that. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know how to handle it in SQL but you can use `proc datasets` instead without having to rewrite the dataset, just working at the metadata level:

```
proc datasets lib=libname memtype=data;
    modify dsname;
    attrib _all_ format=;
run;
```

Comment: Just to note, if I only want to remove the `format` for `var1`, I can put `format var1;`